# Waypoints in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-waypoints

I'm trying to use Waypoints with Wordpress, but can't seem to get it to work.

Here's my set up:

```
function wpResources(){
   wp_enqueue_style('style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/stylesheet.css', false, '1.0', 'all');
   wp_enqueue_script('sparkscripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/sparkscripts.js',array('jquery') );
   wp_register_script('jquery.waypoints', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.waypoints.js',array('jquery'));
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery.waypoints');
}
  add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpResources');
```

I have tried to look online without any luck.

Here's the simplest thing I am trying to run.

```
 var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

 $j(document).ready(function() {

 var $jcontent = $j('article.front');

    $jcontent.waypoint(function (event, direction){
        console.log('woo!');
        }, {offset: 900});

    });
});
```

**EDIT**

Figured this out!

I had a `reset.css` file that was setting `overflow-x: hidden` and therefore not recognizing any scrolling. Now, I'm not sure why, but I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: What kind of error are you seeing?

Comment: @rnevius I'm not, that's the weird part.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if you can use `wp_register_script` inside the `wp_enqueue_script` filter, don't quote me on that! Just try this instead.

**Note:** `jquery` and `waypoints` need to be queued before `myscript`

### functions.php

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'waypoints', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.waypoints.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );

wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/myscript.js', array( 'jquery', 'waypoints' ), '1.0', true );
```

### myscript.js

```
(function($){
    $(function(){
        $('article.front').waypoints(function(e, direction){
            console.info('waypoints initialized');
        }, {offset : 900});
    });
}(jQuery.noConflict(true)));
```

Comment: I switched things around and it will fire, but now it's completely inaccurate. I've been toying with offsets and it doesn't seem to work. I haven't felt this stupid in a while!

Comment: No problem man. I cannot help with offsets as that is something you would need to figure out on your own man. It's purely cosmetic though I'm sure, I don't have any experience with `waypoints.js`